# How to get the details of a group object in MS Visio through C#

Tags: c#, interop, visio, flowchart

I have a shape object drawn as a 'group' with text as 'P0', The group object contains two other small shape objects with text as 'P1'.

[image]

How can i get the details of this group object such that i can have an access to the text of all three shape objects - 'P0', 'P1', 'P1'. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that:

- the target shape is a group shape (and not a container)
- the two sub-shapes are direct children of the group

then the following would work:

```c#
//Some method to get your target shape
var shp = vApp.ActivePage.Shapes.ItemFromID[1];

shp.Characters.Text.Dump($"Group shape - ({shp.NameID})");
foreach (Visio.Shape s in shp.Shapes)
{
    s.Characters.Text.Dump($"Sub shape - ({s.NameID})");
}
```

*Note - the `Dump` method is just an extension method in [LINQPad](https://visualsignals.typepad.co.uk/vislog/2015/12/getting-started-with-c-in-linqpad-with-visio.html), but you could replace this with Console.WriteLine or similar.*

The above code would produce output similar to this (where I've changed the text of the second sub-shape to 'P2'):

[image]

Also, you could just use the `Shape.Text` property directly, but any fields in the text won't be expanded.  So to get the full text as the user sees it, you use `Shape.Characters.Text` instead.